# Long Exact Sequence to compute $H_m(P^n)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was trying to compute the homology groups of $P^n$ by induction using the long exact sequence of homology (Without using cellular homology, although some cellular reasoning can be used, if it can be justified in a simple way without cellular homology). I want to prove that $H_m(P^n)=\mathbb{Z_2}$ for $m<n$ odd, $\mathbb{Z}$ for $m=0$, $0$ for $m$ even and $\mathbb{Z}$ if $m=n$ is odd. The case $n=2$ has already been proven and $P^1\cong S^1$. My attempt goes like this:

> Let first $n>1$ be odd, and let's suppose for every $k<n$ the homology groups are as stated above. Then, using the fact that $P^{n-1}\subseteq P^n$ (As the projection of the points in $S^n$ which have a fixed coordinate null) and that $P^n/P^{n-1}\cong S^n$ we have a long exact sequence of (reduced) homology:
>   $$\cdots \to H_m(P^{n-1})\to H_m(P^n)\to H_m(S^n)\to H_{m-1}(P^{n-1})\to \cdots$$
>   and in particular, taking $m=n$ we have
>   $$\cdots \to H_n(P^{n-1})\to H_n(P^n)\to H_n(S^n)\to H_{n-1}(P^{n-1})\to \cdots$$
>   which gives us ($n-1$ is even), since $H_n(P^{n-1})=H_{n-1}(P^{n-1})=0$, the exact sequence
>   $$0\to H_n(P^n)\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
>   and this gives an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n(P^n)$.
>
> Similarly, for $1\leq m<n$ with $m$ odd (If this case is possible), and since $H_m(P^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}_2$ we have the exact sequence
>   $$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2\to H_m(P^n)\to 0$$
>   and this gives an isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n(P^n)$.
>
> Lastly, for $1<m<n$ even, and since $H_m(P^{n-1})=H_m(S^n)=0$ we have the exact sequence
>   $$0 \to H_m(P^n)\to 0$$
>   which means that $H_m(P^n)=0$.

So, for $n$ odd the job is done.

For $n$ even, I try to do it similarly, but there is a problem.

> Similarly, take $n$ even and suppose that for every $k<n$ the homology groups are as stated above. Then take the long exact sequence: 
>   $$\cdots \to H_m(P^{n-1})\to H_m(P^n)\to H_m(S^n)\to H_{m-1}(P^{n-1})\to \cdots$$
>   For $1\leq m< n-1$ odd we have $H_m(P^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H_m(S^n)=0$. Also $H_{m+1}(S^{n})=0$. So we have the exact sequence
>   $$0 \to H_m(P^{n-1})\to H_m(P^n)\to 0$$
>   which gives an isomorphism between $H_m(P^{n-1})$ and $H_m(P^n)$, so both of them are $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
>   For $1<m<n$ even we have, since $H_m(P^{n-1})=0$ and $H_m(S^n)=0$, the sequence
>   $$0\to H_m(P^n)\to 0$$
>   which results in $H_m(P^n)=0$.
>
> The homology groups we haven't calculated yet are just the ones at the start of the long exact sequence, which is, since $H_n(P^{n-1})=0$,
>   $$0\to H_n(P^n)\to \mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\partial}{\to} \mathbb{Z}\to H_{n-1}(P^n)\to 0.$$

So I want to prove the homomorphism $\partial$ is just multiplication by $2$. I can also see this as $\partial:H_n(P^n,P^{n-1})\to H_n(P^{n-1})$ and as $\partial: H_n(S^n)\to H_n(P^{n-1})$, then I have to pick a generator of either domain and see its image. But I'm not sure how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connecting map $\delta$ lifts a cycle in $S^n$ to a preimage in $P^n$, then takes its boundary, as an element of $P^{n-1}$.

So for $\delta: H_n(S^n)\rightarrow H_n(P^{n-1})$, you lift the generating class $[c]$ of $H_n(S^n)$ itself to the ball with boundary that is the closure of $P^n\setminus P^{n-1}$. Thus $\delta([c])$ is then $d\cdot [b]$, where $[b]$ generates $H_{n-1}(P^{n-1})$, and $d$ is the degree of the covering $S^{n-1}\rightarrow P^{n-1}$, treating $S^{n-1}$ as the boundary of this ball pre-quotient.